# Funcion Rowsource no funciona

Tags: mysql, ms-access

[image: No me muestra las notas del alumno ni el promedio]

No logro que me muestre las notas del alumno en la Lista2 y que me saque el promedio en la Lista3

```
Private Sub Lista1_Click()
Me.txtDNI = Me.Lista1().Column(0)
Me.txtNombre2 = Me.Lista1().Column(1)
Me.Lista2.RowSource = "SELECT DNI, materia, cuatrimestre, Turno, nota FROM NotasXAlumnos WHERE [DNI] LIKE ""*" & Me.txtDNI.Value & " * """
Me.Lista3.RowSource = "SELECT AVG(nota) FROM NotasXAlumnos WHERE [DNI] LIKE "" * " & Me.txtDNI.Value & " * """
End Sub
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado y el obtenido? Lee [ask].

Comment: En los criterios de texto en la cláusula WHERE, no utilices comillas dobles, utiliza comillas simples como `'`. Algo tipo `LIKE '*" & Me.txtDNI.Value & "*'" debería funcionar
`